# Cause of warning when trying to simplify polygons?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I've got a leaflet map and I'm plotting some polygons on top of it. I'm trying to use `rmapshaper::ms_simplify()` to decrease the loading time for the map.

```
    polygons_ll <- (
      spTransform(polygons, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
    )

    polygons_ll <- ms_simplify(polygons_ll)
```

This is all within a R shiny application, which doesn't run after encountering the warning:

```
Warning in sp::proj4string(sp) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
```

The app was functioning before the addition of the `ms_simplify()`.

any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364667/r-4-0-1-not-sure-i-understand-this-message-warning-message-in-proj4stringx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research and trial and error:

```
rgdal::set_rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings(FALSE)
```

will suppress the warning.

I ended up using:

```
crs <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

polygons_ll <- polygons %>% 
    rgeos::gSimplify(tol=25, topologyPreserve=TRUE) %>% 
    spTransform(crs)

# overwrite untransformed polygons with transformed polygons
polygons@polygons <- polygons@polygons
```

Maps are much faster to load now.